# How to convert an array with a single element that is a hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a minor but annoying issue: my API call often returns an array of a single element, which is a hash as follows:

```
foo = [{"key1" => 1, "key2" => 10}]
```

I have to extract a value from the hash as follows: `foo[0]["key2"]`. Is there a more optimal/correct way of doing this?

Comment: `var = var[0]` and `var["value"]`? or am I missing something?

Comment: you can also do `return.first['key2']` -- depending on what the query is (DB query?), you might also want to go through all the results with `results.each{|r| do_something_with( r['key2] )}`

Comment: What is your problem ?

Comment: Apart from using `first` like Tilo suggests, I don't see any other way to do this. If you are only interested in the first element, why don't you alter your API, so that it only returns a hash and not a hash inside an array?

Comment: Mischa: it's Facebook API. oldergod, Tilo & Dogbert: you are right. I find this not "elegant" enough for Ruby. I think Tilo's is nicer.

Comment: Does a valid response ever contain more than one item in the array?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first element (the hash) either by `[0]` / `first`:

```
foo = [{"key1" => 1, "key2" => 10}]

foo[0]
# => {"key1" => 1, "key2" => 10}

foo.first
# => {"key1" => 1, "key2" => 10}
```

or by using Ruby's parallel assignment:

```
foo, _ = [{"key1" => 1, "key2" => 10}]

foo
# => {"key1" => 1, "key2" => 10}
```

This assigns just the first element to `foo` instead of the whole array.

If you are doing this over and over again, it might be a good idea to implement a custom method on top of the API you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Like Tilo's:

```
 results.each{|r| do_something_with( r['key2] )}
```

You could also do:

```
 results = [{"key1"=>1, "key2"=>10}]
 results, _ = results 
 results.each{|key, result| do_something_with( result )}
```

Replacing `result['key2']` with just `result`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do with the extracted values, either `.each` or `.collect` sounds like your best option. Here's an example with `collect`:

```
results = [{"key1"=>1, "key2"=>10}]
key2_array = results.collect{|result| result["key2"]}
# key2_array contains [10]

results = [{"key1"=>1, "key2"=>10},{"key1"=>2, "key2"=>20},{"key1"=>3, "key2"=>30}]
key2_array = results.collect{|result| result["key2"]}
# key2_array contains [10,20,30]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the question is just of making your code look a bit cleaner, you can write a wrapper method around your API call:

```rb
def my_api_wrapper(x, y, z)
  fb_api_call(x, y, z).first
end

# Later...
foo = my_api_wrapper(x, y, z)
foo["key2"]
```